# Firebase - Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for FirebaseApp

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I'm getting this error and I didn't found a solution anywhere. I added the **FirebaseApp** service into my module and component files and it is not enough.

My project base is from this template: https://long2know.com/2017/04/net-core-angular-vs2017-templates/

My files:

**app.module.browser.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleShared } from './app.shared.module';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { FirebaseProvider } from "../services/FirebaseProvider";

import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';

export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    projectId: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
};

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppModuleShared,
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireDatabaseModule        
    ],
    providers: [
        FirebaseProvider, FirebaseApp,
        { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl },
        { provide: 'BASE_CONFIG', useFactory: getBaseConfig }

    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { FirebaseProvider } from "../../../services/FirebaseProvider";

import { AngularFireModule, FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule, AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    providers: [FirebaseApp, AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseProvider]
})

export class HomeComponent {

    }
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "quix_challenge_dashboard",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "firebase": "^4.1.3",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "xlsx": "0.11.12",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/firebase": "^2.4.31",
    "angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is firebase provider a custom service written by you ?

Comment: yes, is a custom service

Comment: did you add the injectable annotation to the the custom service ?

Comment: yes I have @Injectable annotation